# How to Rotate AWT rectangle in JAVA?

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, rectangles, affinetransform

I am creating a small java 2D game and i want to know if there is any way to rotate AWT rectangle

```
AffineTransform origXform = g2d.getTransform();
AffineTransform newXform = (AffineTransform) origXform.clone();
newXform.rotate(angle, pivotX, pivotY); // pivotX ,pivotY is the starting 
point of the hand image
g2d.setTransform(newXform);
Rectangle arm = new Rectangle(bowX + 5,  bowY + 55, 60, 5);
g2d.drawImage(playerBowReadyImg, bowX, bowY, null);  //hand image
```

on the above code i simply draw the hand image which rotates based on the mouse position, i also set the rectangle on the hand but the problem is rectangle is not rotating along with the hand image.

also i am not using rectangle for any drawing purpose but to detect the collision.

however using g2d.draw(arm); draws the rotated rectangle but it not actually rotate the rectangle it just draws the rotated one.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Ok my question is marked as duplicate so i tried the answers i find there but the code i get only rotate my rectangle for the draw purpose only.

[Image to depict the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b9nC.png)

[image]

now to be more specific the arrow in the image can only detect the collision for the blue rectangle (the original position) instead of the red one (rotated rectangle).

again i don't want to actually draw the rectangle but want to detect the collision when the arrow collide with the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`AffineTransform.createTransformedShape(Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-) which:

> Returns a new `Shape` object defined by the geometry of the specified `Shape` after it has been transformed by this transform.