# Rotating objects in java

Tags: java, 2d, computer-science, game-engine, rectangles

I am creating a 2D platformer game in java, and I want to add a rolling enemy. For that, I have to rotate the getBounds rectangle and the image representing the enemy. Is there any way i can do this, and still be able to use the rotated rectangle for rectangle collision detection? I have been looking at others posts, but they sre creating an new shape, and I want a rotated rectangle, not a new shape. I want to use it for rectangle collision detection like this:

```
 public void collision(LinkedList<GameObject> object){
     for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getID() == ID.RollingEnemy){
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                //collided with rolling at players bottom
            }
            if(getBoundsTop().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                //collided with rolling at players top
            }
            if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                //collided with rolling at players left
            }
            if(getBoundsRight().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
                //collided with rolling at players right
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/q/46203332/8587776

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out! But do this work for rectangle .getBounds() collision? 